# Workaround for break-after: avoid-column?

Tags: html, css

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after#browser_compatibility), there is actually no support for `break-after: avoid-column;` in any browsers. The only thing, that is supported ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside#browser_compatibility)), is `break-inside: avoid-column;`.

Unfortunately, this is not what I need. I have a multi-column layout with different headings. I want to prevent, that a heading is ending on a column, while the text is starting on the next column. I have a picture to demonstrate:

[image: column-example]

This example is saved here: https://jsfiddle.net/p5ks8zq9/

The perfect solution would be, to set a `break-after: avoid-column;` to every heading. But because this is not supported, I need a workaround.

My first idea was to use `break-inside: avoid-column;`. I could use a `div` around the heading and the following `<p>`. But there would be a problem, if the following paragraph is too long to fit, as this example demonstrates: https://jsfiddle.net/p5ks8zq9/2/

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem with a workaround?

Comment: on chrome, both links, work as you expect them to

Comment: In the first example I didn't use any css for breaks. It maybe looks different for you, because your screen is different then mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could solve it with JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var headings = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
    headings.forEach(element => {
        var next = element.nextElementSibling;
        while (element.offsetLeft < next.offsetLeft) {
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), element);
        }
    });
});
```

This script goes through every `h1`-element and compares the `offsetLeft` with the next `p`-element. If they don't have the same offsetLeft, the script will insert as much `<br>` as necessary.

Unfortunately, in Safari this way is very slow, if the text is big.